# $v(t) = \int_{t_0}^t u(\tau) \mathop{d\tau} $ is weakly differentiable

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Let E subset of R be an open interval and $p \in [1, \infty)$.
We should show the following:

For $ u \in L^p(E)$ and $t_0 \in E$ show that

$v(t) = \int_{t_0}^t u(\tau) \mathop{d \tau} $ is weakly differentiable and that $v'=u$ almost everywhere.

Comment: Hint: what is the definition of a weak derivative?

Comment: Weak derivative is: For $u$ a function in the Lebesgue space 
$L^1[a.b]$: We say that v in $L^1[a.b]$ is weak derivative of u:
$\int_a^b u \omega'(t)dt = -\int_a^b v(t) \omega(t)dt$

Comment: How can the solution be properly written? Thank you @SeanRoberson

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I actually have this answer, but would appreciate an explanation as there are some steps I do not understand.
Thank you!

Comment: Which steps do you not understand?

Comment: The ones after using Fubini's theorem, I am stuck there.
And how should I conclude that v'=g almost everywhere? @Jeff